# Get value from other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a site where I want to pick up a value and save it in my script, but the value is inside a div on a different page. I have tried so many different things by now, and I cant get it to work.

Do anyone have a idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's under different domain, there's no option due to cross-origin policy with default configuration.

Comment: Do an ajax call and get the text inside the div

Comment: Maybe it is more efficient to retrieve only the requested value via AJAX, not the whole page.

Comment: actually, if its under a different domain and that domain configures cross origin resource sharing, you can grab it using, e.g., an ajax call

Comment: Its on a subpage,

But the idea is that inside that div I use php to get a total number of wordpress post I have posted. The goal with getting the div is to get that number. Maybe I am doing that in the wrong way ?

Comment: You can definitely use ajax if it's a subpage, same domain

Comment: Can you show a example ?

Comment: Btw tried to use load() and I could send a div to a other div, but I could not pick up the value and save it in my script.. :/

Comment: if you are trying to retrieve a value , consider using data !! http://api.jquery.com/data/ , or just post example , cause i feel confused right now !

Comment: you could potentially do it server side with webClient option in .NET. What programming interface are you working with?

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure you have the cross-origin allowed , then just use load , and retreive that specific div

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

where result is the div you want to store data inside , and container is the div on the other page.

will also save time and traffic to load the whole page using get.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

Comment: @JosephPoirier Hopefully you have fully read my answer , and haven't skipped first line :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $.get("pageurl",function(data){
      $("yourdiv").html(data);
 });
```

OR Better

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "YourPageURL",
    success: function(result) {
        var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result); // Instead of div tag you can use specific id with div

    },
});
```

Comment: Check the second option

Comment: Where do I save it to a variable ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you just said.

Comment: This get all of the page, but I just want one div saved in a variable

Comment: USe specific ID on that div or class `#whateverid` OR `.myclass` instead of `<div>` in ajax call